# How to substract one day from a date in MySQL timestamp data type?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, date, timestamp

In my Worpdress site I am using the function [current time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) to return the current date in MySQL timestamp data type format.

My goal is to perfom some operations on the result (like substracting 1 day). I found on the web  `date_sub` but the requirement is that its parameter should be a `DateTime` type.

> Warning: date_sub() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\wp-content\themes\twentyten\header.php on line 107

How can I perform substraction on the  MySQL timestamp data type format, or is there a Worpdress function that returns current date in `DataTime` format?

You help is always appreciated.

Comment: Use DateTime::createFromFormat with the mysql date format.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback to my question. I am read about createFromFormat on PHP manual but still cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new DateInterval("P1D"));
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

If you aren't familiar with it, you should look at PHP SPL Date/Time classes. They are immensely useful and make this type of thing very easy.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is working when I add to it the use of date() function instead of current_time Wordpress function (as advised by tntu above ) . thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the date() function. when you call new DateTime() with no arguments, it uses the current time.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP date function can return date in whatever format you want.**

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - (1 * 86400));
```

This will generate curent time in unix and take one day out.
If fed as second param to date function it will be converted in that format.

```
$a_day_ago = time() - (1 * 86400);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

**If you wish to do it directly in MySQL.**

Date and time:

```
NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Just date:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: I used this instead the the current_time Wordpress function + the solution provided by adear11 to make substarction. It is workin now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
function longdate($timestamp)
{
return date("l F jS Y", $timestamp);
}
?>
```

If you need to print out the date 17 days ago, you now just
have to issue the following call:

```
echo longdate(time() - 17 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

which passes to longdate the current Unix timestamp less the number of seconds since
17 days ago (17 days × 24 hours × 60 minutes × 60 seconds).